# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null error console

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to use media query JS, but when the device is minimized or enlarged an error appears.

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // media query event handler
  if (matchMedia) {
    const mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1100px)");
    mq.addListener(WidthChange);
    WidthChange(mq);
  }
  // media query change
  function WidthChange(mq) {
    if (mq.matches) {
      const h = document.querySelector(".right-bar");
      h.insertAdjacentHTML(
        "afterend",
        "<div class='header-mobile'><label class='show-menu-btn' for='chk'><i class='fas fa-align-justify'/></label><label class='hide-menu-btn' for='chk'><i class='fas fa-times'/></label><label class='search-menu-btn' for='check'><i class='fas fa-search'/></label><label class='tutup-menu-btn' for='check'><i class='fas fa-times'/></label></div>"
      );

      // ambil semua element icon
      const ambil = document.querySelector(".hide-menu-btn");
      const ambil1 = document.querySelector(".show-menu-btn");
      const ambil2 = document.querySelector(".search-menu-btn");
      const ambil3 = document.querySelector(".tutup-menu-btn");

      // hilangkan icon tutup
      ambil.style.display = "none";
      ambil3.style.display = "none";

      // menambahkan element p HTML header
      ambil1.addEventListener("click", function () {
        const l = document.querySelector("#search-box");
        l.insertAdjacentHTML(
          "afterend",
          "<p id='cons'>TERHUBUNG KE ADMIN</p>"
        );

        const divbaru = document.createElement("p");
        const tulisanbaru = document.createTextNode(
          "2020@admin.com All right reserved"
        );
        divbaru.appendChild(tulisanbaru);

        const d1 = document.querySelector(".right-bar");
        d1.appendChild(divbaru);

        d1.style.left = "0";
        ambil1.style.display = "none";
        ambil.style.display = "block";
      });

      ambil.addEventListener("click", function () {
        const k = document.querySelector("#cons");
        k.remove();

        const e = document.querySelector(".right-bar p");
        e.remove();

        ambil.style.display = "none";
        ambil1.style.display = "block";

        const f = document.querySelector(".right-bar");
        f.style.left = "-101%";
      });
    } else {
      const g = document.querySelector(".header-mobile");
      g.remove();

      const a = document.querySelector(".right-bar");
      a.style.left = &#39;-101%&#39;;

      const m = document.querySelector("#cons");
      m.remove();

      const z = document.querySelector(".right-bar p");
      z.remove();
    }
  }
</script>
```

I have a code like the one below, but the error on Google Chrome states the following:

[image: error in console]

It comes from here:

[image: location of the error]

Comment: 1. Is there an element with the class `header-mobile`? 2. Where is the script located, in the `<head>` or before closing the `</body>`?

Comment: Also `a.style.left = &#39;-101%&#39;;` should probably be `a.style.left = '-101%';`

Comment: <body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header id="header-wrapper">
<div class="right-bar" style="left: -101%;">
<nav id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div id="search-box">
<div id="sosial">
<ul>
<li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</header>
</div>
</body>

Comment: hallo reyno, element header-mobile when the device is minimized